# Is it possible to substitute wind speed for the speed of an aircraft in the lift equation $L = \frac12 dv^2sCL$

Tags: aerodynamics, lift

As in, how would you calculate the amount of lift an aircraft experiences, if for example the plane itself was stationary in a wind tunnel but is subject to high wind speeds and as a result experiences lift. I understand that in the equation above $v$ is the speed of an aircraft but can wind speed be substituted for it in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how unsecured airplanes at small airfields move and get damaged.

They get tied down to avoid this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, v should be the air speed relative to the aircraft, including wind. Only then will gusts be included in the lift calculation, and gust loads can become [quite severe](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/russia/12198573/Russian-plane-crash-dozens-reported-dead-latest.html).